# Bijectiveness in a neighborhood of $(0,\pi/2)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

**Question:**

Define $g: \mathbb{R^2}\to \mathbb{R^2}$ by $g(x,y)=(y\cos x,(x+y)\sin y)$.
Show that g maps a neighborhood of $(0,\pi/2)$ bijectively to a neighborhood of $(\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

**What I did/think:**
I don't know where to start, but I think it would have something to do with the derivative of g, which can be somewhat easily be calculated to be \begin{bmatrix}
    -y\sin x & \sin y \\
    \cos x & (x+y)\cos y + \sin y
\end{bmatrix}
This matrix at $(0,\pi/2)$ would be
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\
    1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
but I'm unsure how to go about using this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does have something to do with the (total) derivative of $ g $: it's an application of the *inverse function theorem*

[from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem):]

> For functions of more than one variable, the theorem states that if $ F $ is a continuously differentiable function from an open set of $ \mathbb{R}^n $ into $ \mathbb{R}^m $, and the total derivative is invertible at a point $ p $ (i.e., the Jacobian determinant of $ F $ at $ p $ is non-zero), then $ F $ is invertible near $ p $: an inverse function to $ F $ is defined on some neighborhood of $ q = F(p). $

Since $ g $ is continuously (in fact, infinitely) differentiable on $ \mathbb{R^2} $, which of course is an open subset of itself, you just need to notice the matrix at $ (0, \pi/2) $ is invertible, since its determinant equals $ -1 $